# How to call the original JavaScript function which has been overridden by an extension first?

Tags: javascript, firefox, preventdefault, firefox-addon-webextensions, eventhandler

There's a Firefox extension which modifies the native `preventDefault` function via

```js
Object.defineProperty(Event.prototype, 'preventDefault', ...
```

before my JavaScript script executed. So, when I call `preventDefault` function, the modified function would be called instead of the original one. The behavior of the function is changed by the extension.

For me, there's two way to bypass the extension:

1. Get the native preventDefault function before the extension executed, but my script always executed after the extension even I put my script in head tag.
2. Implement the preventDefault function by myself, but I don't know how to.

Or this's some alternative ways?

Comment: Any reason why you need to bypass this? If users install strange extensions that hack the JS engine, it's their issue if websites stop working, not yours. Otherwise I think the only way would indeed be re-implement it yourself.

Comment: Add a line in the source code of the library to store the original reference in a global variable that you can use to call it

Comment: @AhmadWabbi You mean add a line in the extension source? If add a line in my source, but the extension source always executes before my code...

Comment: @this.lau_ Is it possible to re-implement preventDefault function by my self? And how to if it's possible?

Comment: It's hard because you'll have to modify the internal state of the event. I wouldn't know how to do it myself but you might get there via trial and errors.

Comment: @Xhua Yeah. Add a line in the extension source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Get the native preventDefault function before the extension executed, but my script always executed after the extension even I put my script in head tag.

This is not possible. The extension has chosen to run prior to your HTML being loaded (i.e. the extension is running at [`document_start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts#run_at)). Extensions get to run code first, if they want to. This is as the browser is designed/intended. If the extension changes the prototype, you will not have direct access to the function which has been overridden.

> 2. Implement the preventDefault function by myself, but I don't know how to.

Basically, you can't. The `.preventDefault()` method is the way that you can affect the browser-internal data structure that represents the event in a way that will cause the browser to not call the default action. Even removing the element from the DOM will not prevent the default action. There's no way for you to affect if the default action will be taken, or not, other than calling `.preventDefault()`.

All you can do is detect that the `.preventDefault()` method has been overridden and alert the user that your website does not function properly with that extension installed/active. In this case, you could, probably, detect that the `.preventDefault()` method has been changed by comparing what is returned by `Event.prototype.preventDefault.toString()` to what you expect it to return when the method has not been overridden.

Comment: I really agree with you to detect if the method is overridden. Actually we can directly detect the extension via a simple way since it modified a few of other javascript default behaviors also.